# Kubernetes Python API get all crs

Tags: python, kubernetes

I want to use the Python Kubernetes Client to retrieve *all* CRs, because I want to delete them. The latter can easily be done with `delete_namespaced_custom_object` from the `CustomObjectsApi`. But first, I need a list containing all of them, so an equivalent to `k get crd -A`, which cannot be found in the docu. Is there a trick? I do not want to call `list_namespaced_custom_object` for all of them, or better said: I do not even know all of them beforehand, so this needs to be a solution that gets all CRs. I really want to use the Python Client and not do a subprocess `k get crd -A`, since this can lead to many problems (error handling etc).

Comment: please share what you tried so far

Comment: Can't do that, since I do not know what the correct call to the API would look like.

Answer (score 2):

Use the API method: [`list_cluster_custom_object`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md#list_cluster_custom_object).

There are some concepts to clarify:

1. `k get crd` is used to get all `CRD` resource objects, `-A` option is useless;
2. Say, you have a custom resource type called `application`. `kubectl get application -A` gets all `application`(custom resource) objects in all namespaces;
3. `kubectl get application -A --v 6` will show you the specific **HTTP request** it sends to apiserver, which is in the form `GET /apis/{group}/{version}/{plural}`;

Querying the [api endpoints](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md#documentation-for-api-endpoints) table, you can find that the corresponding API method is `list_cluster_custom_object`.

Comment: `list_cluster_custom_object` works, if you know the exact name of the resource. But if you do not know it, what do you do then? You are correct, you would first do `k get crd`, and with the list returned, you can do `list_cluster_custom_object`. But I want to only use the Python API, not the CLI. How can you do `k get crd` with the Python API?

Comment: @harrisonfooord Your could easily find the API method: [list_custom_resource_definition](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/ApiextensionsV1Api.md#list_custom_resource_definition)